Problems using octomap to raycast a point in front of the robot
I'm trying to create a ROS2 service that returns a 3D point the robot is currently looking at. I'm struggling to get it to consistently work, I believe my issues are with the way I'm subscribing to the octomap topic (I think it sometimes causes a segfault), and with how I'm getting the direction for raycasting. If it is able to update the internal map it can't always get a point (despite point the robot in front of an obstacle), and if it does get a point it doesn't seem to be the correct point.
// in node's class definition in the header
  octomap_msgs::msg::Octomap latestOctomapMsg;
  octomap::OcTree tree;


// The subscriber created in the constructor
pointCloudSubscriber = create_subscription<octomap_msgs::msg::Octomap>(
      "/octomap_full", 10,
      [this](const octomap_msgs::msg::Octomap::SharedPtr msg) {
        std::lock_guard l(mutex);
        RCLCPP_DEBUG(this->get_logger(), "Got octotree");
        latestOctomapMsg = *msg;
        tree.clear();
        octomap_msgs::readTree<octomap::OcTree>(&tree, latestOctomapMsg);
      });


// The callback for when the service is called
void Perception::service_callback(
    const std::shared_ptr<avatar_msgs::srv::RetrievePoint::Request> &request,
    std::shared_ptr<avatar_msgs::srv::RetrievePoint::Response> response) {
  std::lock_guard l(mutex);

  const std::string toFrame = "map"; // the frame_id in the octomap msgs
  const std::string fromFrame = "oak_rgb_camera_frame"; // Center of the camera points forward

  geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped t;

  // Get the current transform of the camera in the map's frame
  try {
    t = tf_buffer->lookupTransform(toFrame, fromFrame, tf2::TimePointZero);
  } catch (const tf2::TransformException &ex) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Could not transform %s to %s: %s",
                 toFrame.c_str(), fromFrame.c_str(), ex.what());
  }

  tf2::Stamped<tf2::Transform> transform;
  tf2::fromMsg(t, transform);

  // Convert to eigen datatypes
  Eigen::Isometry3d transformMatrix = tf2::transformToEigen(t);
  auto rotationMatrix = transformMatrix.rotation();

  // This is what I'm really not sure about, I've tried a few things for this and am just at a loss.
  Eigen::Quaterniond quat(rotationMatrix);
  Eigen::Vector3d rotation = rotationMatrix.col(0);

  Eigen::Quaterniond direction;
  tf2::fromMsg(t.transform.rotation, direction);

  octomap::point3d out;
  response->found =
      tree.castRay(octomap::pointTfToOctomap(transform.getOrigin()),
                   octomap::point3d{static_cast<float>(rotation.x()),
                                    static_cast<float>(rotation.y()),
                                    static_cast<float>(rotation.z())},
                   out);

  if (!response->found) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "No point found");
    return;
  }

  geometry_msgs::msg::Point point = octomap::pointOctomapToMsg(out);
  if (!request->output_frame_id.empty()) {
    try {
      auto tf = tf_buffer->lookupTransform(request->output_frame_id, toFrame,
                                           tf2::TimePointZero);
      tf2::doTransform(octomap::pointOctomapToMsg(out), point, tf);
    } catch (std::exception &ex) {
      RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Could not transform %s to %s: %s",
                   toFrame.c_str(), fromFrame.c_str(), ex.what());
    }
  }

  // Publish the point to debug it in rviz
  geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped p;
  p.header = t.header;
  p.pose.position.x = point.x;
  p.pose.position.y = point.y;
  p.pose.position.z = point.z;
  raycast_pose->publish(p);

  RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Got point (%f, %f, %f)", point.x, point.y,
              point.z);

  response->point = point;
}

